# Rewrite an integral according to elliptic function of the second kind

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, special-functions

When I try to review the solution process of solving the 2-D Ising model, I get interested in a integral, which is considered to be impossible to get a closed-form.

The integral is $I=\int_0^\pi\log\left(1+\sqrt{(1-\kappa^2\sin^2x)}\right)dx$

If we split the integral interval into two parts, then

$I=2\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\log\left(1+\sqrt{(1-\kappa^2\sin^2x)}\right)dx$

Taking advantage of the Taylor expansion of logarithmic function,namely

$\log(1+x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}x^n}{n}$

the integral turns out to be

$I=2\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\sqrt{1-\kappa^2\sin^2x}\right)^n~dx$

When $n=1$ ,the first item is nothing but the complete elliptic integral of the second kind:

$E(\kappa)=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\sqrt{1-\kappa^2\sin^2x}~dx$

So, I wonder whether or not can we rewrite the integral $I$ according to the complete elliptic integral of the second kind $E(\kappa)$ ? Once we succeed, the result will be much more beautiful!

Thanks!

Comment: Well,you must be joking!Hint:$\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}f({\sin}^{2}x)dx=-\int_{\pi/2}^{0}f({\sin}^{2}u)du=\int_{0}^{pi/2}f({\sin}^{2}u)du$

Answer (score 2):

Note that the following procedure is wrong (but I don't know the reason):

$I=\int_0^\pi\ln\left(1+\sqrt{1-\kappa^2\sin^2x}\right)dx$

$=\dfrac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}\ln\left(1+\sqrt{1-\kappa^2\sin^2x}\right)dx$ $\left(\ln\left(1+\sqrt{1-\kappa^2\sin^2x}\right)~\text{is a periodic function of period}~\pi\right)$

$=\dfrac{1}{2}\left[x\ln\left(1+\sqrt{1-\kappa^2\sin^2x}\right)\right]_0^{2\pi}-\dfrac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}x~d\left(\ln\left(1+\sqrt{1-\kappa^2\sin^2x}\right)\right)$

$=\dfrac{\pi\ln2}{2}+\dfrac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}\dfrac{\kappa^2x\sin x\cos x}{\sqrt{1-\kappa^2\sin^2x}\left(1+\sqrt{1-\kappa^2\sin^2x}\right)}dx$

$=\dfrac{\pi\ln2}{2}+\dfrac{1}{2}\int_{2\pi}^0\dfrac{\kappa^2(2\pi-x)\sin(2\pi-x)\cos(2\pi-x)}{\sqrt{1-\kappa^2\sin^2(2\pi-x)}\left(1+\sqrt{1-\kappa^2\sin^2(2\pi-x)}\right)}d(2\pi-x)$

$=\dfrac{\pi\ln2}{2}+\dfrac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}\dfrac{\kappa^2(2\pi-x)\sin x\cos x}{\sqrt{1-\kappa^2\sin^2x}\left(1+\sqrt{1-\kappa^2\sin^2x}\right)}dx$

$\therefore2I=\pi\ln2+\int_0^{2\pi}\dfrac{2\kappa^2\pi\sin x\cos x}{\sqrt{1-\kappa^2\sin^2x}\left(1+\sqrt{1-\kappa^2\sin^2x}\right)}dx$

$I=\dfrac{\pi\ln2}{2}-\left[\pi\ln\left(1+\sqrt{1-\kappa^2\sin^2x}\right)\right]_0^{2\pi}$

$I=\dfrac{\pi\ln2}{2}$

In fact the following procedure is really correct:

$I=\int_0^\pi\ln\left(1+\sqrt{1-\kappa^2\sin^2x}\right)dx=2\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\ln\left(1+\sqrt{1-\kappa^2\sin^2x}\right)dx$

$\dfrac{dI}{d\kappa}=-\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\dfrac{2\kappa\sin^2x}{\sqrt{1-\kappa^2\sin^2x}\left(1+\sqrt{1-\kappa^2\sin^2x}\right)}dx$

$=-\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\dfrac{2\kappa\sin^2x\left(1-\sqrt{1-\kappa^2\sin^2x}\right)}{\sqrt{1-\kappa^2\sin^2x}\left(1+\sqrt{1-\kappa^2\sin^2x}\right)\left(1-\sqrt{1-\kappa^2\sin^2x}\right)}dx$

$=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\dfrac{2\kappa\sin^2x\left(\sqrt{1-\kappa^2\sin^2x}-1\right)}{(1-(1-\kappa^2\sin^2x))\sqrt{1-\kappa^2\sin^2x}}dx$

$=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\dfrac{2\kappa\sin^2x\left(\sqrt{1-\kappa^2\sin^2x}-1\right)}{\kappa^2\sin^2x\sqrt{1-\kappa^2\sin^2x}}dx$

$=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\dfrac{2}{\kappa}dx-\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\dfrac{2}{\kappa\sqrt{1-\kappa^2\sin^2x}}dx$

When $0\leq\kappa\leq1$ ,

$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\dfrac{2}{\kappa}dx-\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\dfrac{2}{\kappa\sqrt{1-\kappa^2\sin^2x}}dx$

$=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\dfrac{2}{\kappa}dx-\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\dfrac{2}{\kappa}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(2n)!\kappa^{2n}\sin^{2n}x}{4^n(n!)^2}dx$

$=-\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{(2n)!\kappa^{2n-1}\sin^{2n}x}{2^{2n-1}(n!)^2}dx$

For $\int\sin^{2n}x~dx$ , where $n$ is any natural number,

$\int\sin^{2n}x~dx=\dfrac{(2n)!x}{4^n(n!)^2}-\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{(2n)!((k-1)!)^2\sin^{2k-1}x\cos x}{4^{n-k+1}(n!)^2(2k-1)!}+C$

$\therefore-\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{(2n)!\kappa^{2n-1}\sin^{2n}x}{2^{2n-1}(n!)^2}dx$

$=-\left[\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{((2n)!)^2\kappa^{2n-1}x}{2^{4n-1}(n!)^4}-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{((2n)!)^2\kappa^{2n-1}((k-1)!)^2\sin^{2k-1}x\cos x}{2^{4n-2k+1}(n!)^4(2k-1)!}\right]_0^\frac{\pi}{2}$

$=-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{((2n)!)^2\pi\kappa^{2n-1}}{16^n(n!)^4}$

$\therefore I=-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{(2n)!(2n-1)!\pi\kappa^{2n}}{16^n(n!)^4}+c$

$\because I(0)=\int_0^\pi\ln2~dx=[x\ln2]_0^\pi=\pi\ln2$

$\therefore c=\pi\ln2$

Hence $I=\pi\ln2-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{(2n)!(2n-1)!\pi\kappa^{2n}}{16^n(n!)^4}$

Comment: Numerically this holds only when $\kappa=0$

Comment: Hello,Peter,thanks for your help,but I can not agree with your conclusion,which said the integral $I$ is independent with the parameter $\kappa$.

Answer (score 1):

A special occasion, when $\kappa=1$.

The integral will be

$I=2\int_0^{\pi/2}\log(1+{\cos}x)dx$

Clearly,

$I=4C-\pi\log(2)\approx1.4868$

where $C$ is the well-known Catalan's Constant.

Answer (score 0):

---

Define the function $\mathcal{I}:[-1,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ via the definite integral

$$\mathcal{I}{\left(\kappa\right)}:=\int_{0}^{\pi}\mathrm{d}\theta\,\ln{\left(1+\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}\sin^{2}{\left(\theta\right)}}\right)}.$$

We seek a closed-form expression for $\mathcal{I}$ in terms of elementary and (more or less) well-known special functions.

It should be obvious from the definition of $\mathcal{I}$ that

$$\mathcal{I}{\left(-\kappa\right)}=\mathcal{I}{\left(\kappa\right)};~~~\small{\kappa\in[-1,1]},$$

$$\mathcal{I}{\left(0\right)}=\pi\ln{(2)},$$

and it has already been shown in another answer that

$$\mathcal{I}{\left(1\right)}=-\pi\ln{\left(2\right)}+4C,$$

where $C$ denotes Catalan's constant.

It remains to evaluate $\mathcal{I}{\left(\kappa\right)}$ for the $0<\kappa<1$ case. Below, we will derive an expression for $\mathcal{I}$ in terms of the generalized hypergeometric function $_4F_3$.

---

For any $\kappa\in[-1,1]$, it can be shown that

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}{\left(\kappa\right)}
&=\int_{0}^{\pi}\mathrm{d}\theta\,\ln{\left(1+\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}\sin^{2}{\left(\theta\right)}}\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\theta\,\ln{\left(1+\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}\sin^{2}{\left(\theta\right)}}\right)}+\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi}\mathrm{d}\theta\,\ln{\left(1+\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}\sin^{2}{\left(\theta\right)}}\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\theta\,\ln{\left(1+\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}\sin^{2}{\left(\theta\right)}}\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\int_{\pi-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi-\pi}\mathrm{d}\vartheta\,(-1)\ln{\left(1+\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}\sin^{2}{\left(\pi-\vartheta\right)}}\right)};~~~\small{\left[\theta=\pi-\vartheta\right]}\\
&=2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\theta\,\ln{\left(1+\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}\sin^{2}{\left(\theta\right)}}\right)}.\\
\end{align}$$

Assuming $0<\kappa<1$, we then find

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}{\left(\kappa\right)}
&=2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\theta\,\ln{\left(1+\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}\sin^{2}{\left(\theta\right)}}\right)}\\
&=2\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}x^{2}}\right)}}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}};~~~\small{\left[\theta=\arcsin{(x)}\right]}\\
&=2\bigg{[}\arcsin{\left(1\right)}\ln{\left(1+\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}1^{2}}\right)}-\arcsin{\left(0\right)}\ln{\left(1+\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}0^{2}}\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\arcsin{\left(x\right)}\frac{d}{dx}\ln{\left(1+\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}x^{2}}\right)}\bigg{]};~~~\small{I.B.P.}\\
&=\pi\ln{\left(1+\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}}\right)}-2\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\arcsin{\left(x\right)}\left[-\frac{\kappa^{2}x}{\left(1+\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}x^{2}}\right)\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}x^{2}}}\right]\\
&=\pi\ln{\left(1+\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}}\right)}+2\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\kappa^{2}x\arcsin{\left(x\right)}}{\left(1+\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}x^{2}}\right)\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}x^{2}}}\\
&=\pi\ln{\left(1+\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}}\right)}+2\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\kappa^{2}x\left(1-\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}x^{2}}\right)}{\left(1+\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}x^{2}}\right)\left(1-\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}x^{2}}\right)}\cdot\frac{\arcsin{\left(x\right)}}{\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}x^{2}}}\\
&=\pi\ln{\left(1+\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}}\right)}+2\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\kappa^{2}x\left(1-\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}x^{2}}\right)}{\kappa^{2}x^{2}}\cdot\frac{\arcsin{\left(x\right)}}{\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}x^{2}}}\\
&=\pi\ln{\left(1+\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}}\right)}+2\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1-\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}x^{2}}}{\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}x^{2}}}\cdot\frac{\arcsin{\left(x\right)}}{x}\\
&=\pi\ln{\left(1+\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}}\right)}+2\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\arcsin{\left(x\right)}}{x}\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}x^{2}}}-1\right]\\
&=\pi\ln{\left(1+\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}}\right)}+2\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\arcsin{\left(x\right)}}{x}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\kappa^{2}x^{2}y}{\left(1-\kappa^{2}x^{2}y^{2}\right)^{3/2}}\\
&=\pi\ln{\left(1+\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}}\right)}+2\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\kappa^{2}xy\arcsin{\left(x\right)}}{\left(1-\kappa^{2}x^{2}y^{2}\right)^{3/2}}\\
&=\pi\ln{\left(1+\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}}\right)}+2\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\kappa^{2}yx\arcsin{\left(x\right)}}{\left(1-\kappa^{2}y^{2}x^{2}\right)^{3/2}}\\
&=\pi\ln{\left(1+\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}}\right)}+2\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{1}{y}\left[\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}y^{2}}}-\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(1-x^{2}\right)\left(1-\kappa^{2}y^{2}x^{2}\right)}}\right]\\
&=\pi\ln{\left(1+\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}}\right)}+2\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{1}{y}\left[\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}y^{2}}}-K{\left(\kappa\,y\right)}\right],\\
\end{align}$$

where the elliptic integrals of the first kind are given here by

$$F{\left(\theta,k\right)}:=\int_{0}^{\theta}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-k^{2}\sin^{2}{\left(\varphi\right)}}};~~~\small{k\in(-1,1)\land\theta\in\mathbb{R}},$$

$$K{\left(k\right)}:=F{\left(\frac{\pi}{2},k\right)};~~~\small{k\in(-1,1)}.$$

Then,

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}{\left(\kappa\right)}
&=\pi\ln{\left(1+\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}}\right)}+2\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{1}{y}\left[\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}y^{2}}}-K{\left(\kappa\,y\right)}\right]\\
&=\pi\ln{\left(1+\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}}\right)}+2\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{1}{y}\left[\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}y^{2}}}-\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi}{2}-K{\left(\kappa\,y\right)}\right]\\
&=\pi\ln{\left(1+\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}}\right)}+2\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{1}{y}\left[\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}y^{2}}}-\frac{\pi}{2}\right]\\
&~~~~~+2\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{1}{y}\left[\frac{\pi}{2}-K{\left(\kappa\,y\right)}\right]\\
&=\pi\ln{\left(1+\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}}\right)}+\pi\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{1}{y}\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}y^{2}}}-1\right]\\
&~~~~~-2\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{1}{y}\left[K{\left(\kappa\,y\right)}-\frac{\pi}{2}\right].\\
\end{align}$$

The first of the remaining two integrals is elementary. For each $0<\kappa<1$, we obtain

$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{1}{y}\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}y^{2}}}-1\right]
&=\int_{0}^{\kappa}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{t}\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^{2}}}-1\right];~~~\small{\left[\kappa\,y=t\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\kappa^{2}}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{1}{2u}\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u}}-1\right];~~~\small{\left[t^{2}=u\right]}\\
&=\int_{1-\kappa^{2}}^{1}\mathrm{d}v\,\frac{1}{2\left(1-v\right)}\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{v}}-1\right];~~~\small{\left[u=1-v\right]}\\
&=\int_{\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}}}^{1}\mathrm{d}w\,\frac{2w}{2\left(1-w^{2}\right)}\left[\frac{1}{w}-1\right];~~~\small{\left[\sqrt{v}=w\right]}\\
&=\int_{\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}}}^{1}\mathrm{d}w\,\frac{1}{1+w}\\
&=\int_{1+\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}}}^{2}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{x};~~~\small{\left[1+w=x\right]}\\
&=\ln{\left(2\right)}-\ln{\left(1+\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}}\right)}.\\
\end{align}$$

Let the auxiliary function $\mathcal{J}:(0,1)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be given by the remaining unsolved integral,

$$\mathcal{J}{\left(\kappa\right)}:=2\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{1}{y}\left[K{\left(\kappa\,y\right)}-\frac{\pi}{2}\right].$$

We obtain the following expression for $\mathcal{J}$ in terms of generalized hypergeometric functions: for $\kappa\in(0,1)$,

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{J}{\left(\kappa\right)}
&=2\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{1}{y}\left[K{\left(\kappa\,y\right)}-\frac{\pi}{2}\right]\\
&=2\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{1}{y}\left[\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(1-x^{2}\right)\left(1-\kappa^{2}x^{2}y^{2}\right)}}-\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\right]\\
&=2\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{1}{y}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}x^{2}y^{2}}}-1\right]\\
&=2\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{1}{y}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}v\,\frac{d}{dv}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}x^{2}y^{2}v}}\\
&=2\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{1}{y}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}v\,\frac{\kappa^{2}x^{2}y^{2}}{2\left(1-\kappa^{2}x^{2}y^{2}v\right)^{3/2}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}v\,\frac{\kappa^{2}x^{2}y}{\left(1-\kappa^{2}x^{2}y^{2}v\right)^{3/2}\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}v\,\frac{\kappa^{2}x^{2}y}{\left(1-\kappa^{2}x^{2}y^{2}v\right)^{3/2}\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}v\,\frac{\kappa^{2}x^{2}}{2\left(1-\kappa^{2}x^{2}uv\right)^{3/2}\sqrt{1-x^{2}}};~~~\small{\left[y^{2}=u\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}v\,\frac{\kappa^{2}t}{2\left(1-\kappa^{2}tuv\right)^{3/2}\sqrt{1-t}};~~~\small{\left[x=\sqrt{t}\right]}\\
&=\frac14\kappa^{2}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\sqrt{t}}{\sqrt{1-t}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}v\,\frac{1}{\left(1-\kappa^{2}tuv\right)^{3/2}}\\
&=\frac14\kappa^{2}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\sqrt{t}}{\sqrt{1-t}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,{_2F_1}{\left(\frac32,1;2;\kappa^{2}tu\right)}\\
&=\frac14\kappa^{2}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\sqrt{t}}{\sqrt{1-t}}\,{_3F_2}{\left(\frac32,1,1;2,2;\kappa^{2}t\right)}\\
&=\frac14\kappa^{2}\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac32,\frac12\right)}\,{_4F_3}{\left(\frac32,1,1,\frac32;2,2,2;\kappa^{2}\right)}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{8}\kappa^{2}\,{_4F_3}{\left(\frac32,1,1,\frac32;2,2,2;\kappa^{2}\right)}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{8}\kappa^{2}\,{_4F_3}{\left(1,1,\frac32,\frac32;2,2,2;\kappa^{2}\right)},\\
\end{align}$$

where we've made use of Euler's integral representations for hypergeometric functions; in particular, given $(a,b,c,p,q,r,s)\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}^{7}\land z\in(-\infty,1)$ such that $b<c\land p<q\land r<s$, we have

$${_2F_1}{\left(a,b;c;z\right)}=\frac{1}{\operatorname{B}{\left(b,c-b\right)}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}v\,\frac{v^{b-1}\left(1-v\right)^{c-b-1}}{\left(1-zv\right)^{a}},$$

$${_3F_2}{\left(a,b,p;c,q;z\right)}=\frac{1}{\operatorname{B}{\left(p,q-p\right)}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,u^{p-1}\left(1-u\right)^{q-p-1}\,{_2F_1}{\left(a,b;c;zu\right)},$$

$${_4F_3}{\left(a,b,p,r;c,q,s;z\right)}=\frac{1}{\operatorname{B}{\left(r,s-r\right)}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,t^{r-1}\left(1-t\right)^{s-r-1}\,{_3F_2}{\left(a,b,p;c,q;zt\right)}.$$

Putting it all together, we arrive at the following expression for $\mathcal{I}$:

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}{\left(\kappa\right)}
&=\pi\ln{\left(1+\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}}\right)}+\pi\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{1}{y}\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}y^{2}}}-1\right]\\
&~~~~~-2\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{1}{y}\left[K{\left(\kappa\,y\right)}-\frac{\pi}{2}\right]\\
&=\pi\ln{\left(1+\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}}\right)}+\pi\left[\ln{\left(2\right)}-\ln{\left(1+\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}}\right)}\right]-\mathcal{J}{\left(\kappa\right)}\\
&=\pi\ln{\left(2\right)}-\mathcal{J}{\left(\kappa\right)}\\
&=\pi\ln{\left(2\right)}-\frac{\pi}{8}\kappa^{2}\,{_4F_3}{\left(1,1,\frac32,\frac32;2,2,2;\kappa^{2}\right)}.\blacksquare\\
\end{align}$$

---