# Evaluating the Definite Integral $\int _0 ^{2\pi} y e^{-a\cos\left( y\right)}\, \mathrm{d}y$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

The problem is to solve the following integral:

$$\int _0 ^{2\pi} y e^{-a\cos\left( y\right)}\, \mathrm{d}y$$

where $a$ is a constant.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Can you [edit] your question to include your thoughts and efforts on this problem? What have you tried, and where are you having difficulty? This will help people write an appropriate answer the addresses your problem. Questions that include this information tend to have a much better response.

Comment: According to [wolframe](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x*e^%28-+cosx%29), the indefinite  integral has no sloution in terms of standard functions, is your intention is to have a numeric solution?? if so, what numerical methods are you familiar with ?

Comment: I want solution in the form of modified Bessel function as Io(a)

Comment: Genius  as you are seeking for a specific kind of solution, you have to state that in your question, and please add what have you tried, and what is your  point oof view concernign the problem.

Comment: $$\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-n\:\cos(y)}dy=2\pi I_0(n)$$ . $\int_0^{2\pi}ye^{-n\:\cos(y)}dy$ of course is integrable, but not on closed form with standard Bessel functions. Are you aware  that is the most common situation and that some convenient closed form exist only for a very limited number of cases ? That is why nobody can help you if you refuse to give more information about the context of your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some of my efforts to solve the problem.

First, let us denote your integral by

$$I=\int _0 ^{2\pi} y e^{-a\cos y}\, dy \tag{1}$$

In these types of definite integrals, never forget to use this general identity

$$I=\int_{p}^{q}f(x)dx=\int_{p}^{q}f(p+q-y)dy \tag{2}$$

Which can be proved by the substitution $x = p+q-y$. Then one writes the definite integral as the average of the two expressions above to obtain

$$I=\int_{p}^{q} \frac{1}{2}[f(y)+f(p+q-y)]dy \tag{3}$$

So by choosing $f(y)=ye^{-a\cos y}$, $p=0$, $q=2\pi$, and using $(3)$ we can observe that

$$I=\pi \int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{-a \cos y} dy \tag{4}$$

---

**Method $1$**

You can finish up right here, by noticing that

$$\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-a\:\cos y}dy=2\pi I_0(a) \tag{5}$$

as mentioned in the comments and conclude that

$$\boxed{I=2\pi^2I_0(a)} \tag{6}$$

---

**Method $2$**

Even if we didn't know that something like $(5)$ holds we could go further.

Now, make the substitution $y=\pi-u$, use the relation $\cos(\pi-u)=-\cos u$ and notice the fact that $\cos(-u)=\cos(u)$ to get

$$I=2\pi \int_{0}^{\pi} e^{a \cos u} du \tag{7}$$

Next, by the Taylor series of the exponential function we observe that

$$e^{a \cos u}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{a^n}{n!} \cos^n u \tag{8}$$

So, combining $(7)$ and $(8)$ leads to

$$\begin{align}
I &= 2\pi \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{a^n}{n!} \left( \int_{0}^{\pi}\cos^n u du \right) \\
&= 2\pi \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{a^n}{n!}J_n
\end{align} \tag{9}$$

Also, by using integration by parts once and noticing $\sin^2=1-\cos^2$, one can easily prove that

$$\int \cos^n \alpha x dx= \frac{\sin \alpha x \cos^{n-1} \alpha x}{\alpha n}+\frac{n-1}{n}\int \cos^{n-2} \alpha x dx \tag{10}$$

and hence by choosing $\alpha=1$ and computing the definite integral of $J_n$ we get

$$\begin{align}
& J_n=\frac{n-1}{n}J_{n-2}, \qquad n=2,3,4,...\\
& J_0=\pi \\
& J_1= 0
\end{align}
\tag{11}$$

Hopefully, the recurrence relation is not that much complicated and by a simple argument you can conclude that

$$\begin{align}
J_{2n}&=\pi\frac{(2n)!}{4^nn!^2} \\
J_{2n-1}&=0
\end{align} \tag{12}$$

and finally

$$\begin{align}
I &= 2\pi \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{a^{2n}}{(2n)!}J_{2n} \\
&= \boxed{2\pi^2 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{a^{2n}}{4^nn!^2}} \\
\end{align}
\tag{13}$$

Comment: The values of $J_{2p}=\frac{2p-1}{2p}J_{2(p-1)}$ are not equal to $\pi/2p$.

Comment: @Tom-Tom: Yeah! I noticed that simultaneously with you! :)

Comment: You can compute $J_{2p}$ noticing that $(2p-1)(2p-3)\dots(2\times1-1)=(2p)!/(2^pp!)$. This leads to $J_{2p}=\pi(2p)!/(4^pp!^2)$ and the series $$I=2\pi^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a^{2n}}{4^n n!^2}=2\pi^2I_0(a).$$

Comment: @Tom-Tom: Thanks for the suggestion. I am not good at these sequence thing! :D I will do the changes. :)

Comment: Don't you afraid you will get the wrong procedure like http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/521247?

Comment: @HarryPeter: Sorry I didn't get you. Can you kindly point out my mistake? :)

Answer (score 1):

As a complement to @H.R. 's answer, let us remark that
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\mathrm e^{a\cos x}\mathrm dx=2\pi I_0(a)$$
where $I_0$ is the modified Bessel function of order 0.
The integral is therefore $2\pi^2I_0(a)$.

Answer (score -1):

$\int_0^{2\pi}ye^{-a\cos y}~dy$

$=\int_0^\pi2ye^{-a\cos2y}~d(2y)$

$=\int_0^\pi4ye^{-a(1-2\sin^2y)}~dy$

$=\int_0^\pi4e^{-a}ye^{2a\sin^2y}~dy$

$=\int_0^\pi\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{2^{n+2}e^{-a}a^ny\sin^{2n}y}{n!}dy$

$=\int_0^\pi4e^{-a}y~dy+\int_0^\pi\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{2^{n+2}e^{-a}a^ny\sin^{2n}y}{n!}dy$

For $n$ is any natural number,

$\int\sin^{2n}y~dy=\dfrac{(2n)!y}{4^n(n!)^2}-\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{(2n)!((k-1)!)^2\sin^{2k-1}y~\cos y}{4^{n-k+1}(n!)^2(2k-1)!}+C$

This result can be done by successive integration by parts.

$\therefore\int_0^\pi4e^{-a}y~dy+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\int_0^\pi\dfrac{2^{n+2}e^{-a}a^ny\sin^{2n}y}{n!}dy$

$=[2e^{-a}y^2]_0^\pi+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\int_0^\pi\dfrac{2^{n+2}e^{-a}a^ny}{n!}d\left(\dfrac{(2n)!y}{4^n(n!)^2}-\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{(2n)!((k-1)!)^2\sin^{2k-1}y~\cos y}{4^{n-k+1}(n!)^2(2k-1)!}\right)$

$=2e^{-a}\pi^2+\left[\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{e^{-a}a^n(2n)!y^2}{2^{n-2}(n!)^3}-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{e^{-a}a^n(2n)!((k-1)!)^2y\sin^{2k-1}y~\cos y}{2^{n-2k}(n!)^3(2k-1)!}\right]_0^\pi-\int_0^\pi\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{e^{-a}a^n(2n)!y}{2^{n-2}(n!)^3}-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{e^{-a}a^n(2n)!((k-1)!)^2\sin^{2k-1}y~\cos y}{2^{n-2k}(n!)^3(2k-1)!}\right)dy$

$=2e^{-a}\pi^2+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{e^{-a}a^n(2n)!\pi^2}{2^{n-2}(n!)^3}-\left[\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{e^{-a}a^n(2n)!y^2}{2^{n-1}(n!)^3}-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{e^{-a}a^n(2n)!((k-1)!)^2\sin^{2k}y}{2^{n-2k}(n!)^3(2k)!}\right]_0^\pi$

$=2e^{-a}\pi^2+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{e^{-a}a^n(2n)!\pi^2}{2^{n-2}(n!)^3}-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{e^{-a}a^n(2n)!\pi^2}{2^{n-1}(n!)^3}$

$=2e^{-a}\pi^2+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{e^{-a}a^n(2n)!\pi^2}{2^{n-1}(n!)^3}$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{e^{-a}a^n(2n)!\pi^2}{2^{n-1}(n!)^3}$